# Share question within SE users

Tags: feature-request

I know that there's a way to share  questions from SE in Twitter, fb, g+ etc. Is there any way to share a question to the users of SE? I can't use none of the available options because I do not have accounts in them.

Comment: Um...you share a question with the users of the SE by asking it, no? And the `share` under the tags of a question gives you a link that you can copy anywhere you like

Comment: Or by leaving a comment with the link from `share`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stack Exchange network [is **not** a social network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65261/is-stack-overflow-a-social-networking-site). And the idea of pushing your question onto others has been [strongly rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103086/how-could-i-notify-stack-overflows-expert-users-about-my-new-question). No expert would choose to participate in a site in which any user could nag them effortlessly to personally solve every problem that arises.

If you want your question to have more visibility to everyone (on the site, not the whole network), you can do so, but there is a price. You must [offer a nonrefundable bounty](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) of your own reputation on the question. Open bounties are summarized in the [featured tab](https://physics.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured), and some (but not all) users check there to see if there are questions they can answer given the extra incentive.